# Removing IP address from server takes down unrelated website

Tags: iis, nic, ipv4, bindings

I'm working with a Windows 2008 Server running IIS. One of the websites running in IIS was migrated to another server. As a result, I shut down that site in IIS on the Windows 2008 server. There weren't any issues there. However, when I removed the IP address associated with that site from the local NIC, an 'unrelated' site with a different IP address/binding went down.

The single NIC is set up with multiple IP address i.e.
NIC1: 10.0.1.10, 10.0.1.11, 10.0.1.12, 10.0.1.13, etc.

As an example, I'll say 'Site A' is the website that was removed and it was using IP address 10.0.1.11 and 'Site B' is using IP address 10.0.1.13.

As soon as I removed IP address 10.0.1.11, 'Site B' went down. 'Site B' currently has two bindings. The first binding includes the protocol (HTTP), the host name, the port, and a wildcard IP. The second binding includes the protocol (HTTP), the hostname, the port and the specific IP, 10.0.1.13.

I've doublechecked DNS and have confirmed that the correct IP address is associated with each website.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Beside bindings, have you checked that the actual site configuration or scripts/software don’t contain references to the old IP address or any DNS records that could point at it?

Comment: @MikaelH, No I have not checked that yet, but I will. I did not think of that. Good call, and thanks. One thing I forgot to mention is that the local hosts file had an entry for 'Site B' that pointed to a different IP address but removing that entry and replacing it with the correct IP did not seem to fix the problem.